# Populating field value from another list with JavaScript doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I have a list called 'quotes' and list called 'autoquotenumber'.  'autoquotenumber' only has one item id=1 which is used to keep track of the quote numbers.  I would like to retrieve a column from 'numbers' list whose column name is 'lastnumber' and use it in my quotes list to populate a field called 'quote number' when entering a new item.

I have this functioning with a flow perfectly, however the time it takes for the flow to kick off is too long sometimes a couple of minutes.  I would like to try to get this working with JavaScript if possible.

Unfortunately I'm still learning a lot about this, so any help I can get is appreciated.

I've been trying to piece some things together, and thought i might be getting close with this:

```
var clientContext = null;
var web = null;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(AutoGenerate, "sp.js");

function AutoGenerate() {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query></Query></View>');
    this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(listItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
    var itemId = 1;   
    var targetListItem;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
    var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('AutoQuoteNumberTest');
    targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
    var AutoIncremental = "Quote-" + clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'lastnumber');
    $("input[title^='Quote Number']").val(AutoIncremental);
    $("input[title^='Quote Number']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Unfortunately this is what I get, no number retrieved:

[image]